# Oracle SQL filtering results from a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a query to filter results from two columns of a parameterised query.

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_INSTR('%param1)s', '[|(\\\[]') > 0 AND REGEXP_LIKE(column1.'%param1)s') 
THEN 'Y' END REGEXP_MATCH,
CASE WHEN REGEXP_INSTR('%param1)s', '[|(\\\[]') = 0 AND column1 LIKE '%(param1)s' 
THEN 'Y' END LIKE_MATCH,
```

This creates two columns, REGEXP_MATCH and LIKE_MATCH.

I then want to filter from both of these columns. If REGEXP_MATCH is 'Y' then use a regular expression on param1. If LIKE_MATCH is 'Y' then use a LIKE operator on param1, else use '*' and match everything.

I'm not entirely sure what the best way to do this is though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
WHERE ( REGEXP_INSTR('%param1)s', '[|(\\\[]') > 0 AND REGEXP_LIKE(column1.'%param1)s') 
      ) OR
      (REGEXP_INSTR('%param1)s', '[|(\\\[]') = 0 AND column1 LIKE '%(param1)s'
      ) OR
      (%param1 IS NULL)
```

Comment: I was more looking to filter based on the two columns. If the REGEXP_MATCH has a 'Y' in it we'll use a regular expression, if the LIKE_MATCH has a 'Y' in it we'll use a LIKE operator. If neither have a 'Y' then we'll use the '*' operator.

Comment: @user13435420 . . . This answers the question that you asked here.  If you are "more looking for something", then you should ask an appropriate question.  For the record, you can't filter based on columns defined in the `select` associated with the `where` clause.